# Changing interline

Tags: fontsize

I do not know why, but my code provides a text with different values of interline. To be more clear, let me show my code:

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper, english]{article} 
\usepackage{graphicx,amssymb} 
\textwidth=15cm \hoffset=-1.2cm 
\textheight=25cm \voffset=-2cm 

\pagestyle{empty} 

\date{\today} 
\def\keywords#1{\begin{center}{\bf Keywords}\\{#1}\end{center}} 

\begin{document}

\title{Title}

\author{\textit{Author} \\ 
        University\\\\
       }

\maketitle

\thispagestyle{empty}

\keywords{keywords}
%
%
\vspace{0.7cm}
{\Large{\textbf{Introduction}}}\\\\
%
Text 1
\begin{equation}
    u^{k+1}
\end{equation}
Text 2
%
\begin{footnotesize}
\begin{thebibliography}{9}
 %
\bibitem{blabla} 
Blabla.
\end{thebibliography}
\end{footnotesize}
\end{document}
```

The result is shown below:

[image]

As you can see the text below the formula has an interline smaller than the previous. 
If I remove \begin{footnotesize} and \end{footnotesize} (bibliography), I get what I want (same interline for both text). 
Any suggestion to have same interline and font size smaller for bibliography? Thank you!

Comment: Add a blank line before `\begin{footnotesize}`. Are you sure you want ``{\Large{\textbf{Introduction}}}\\\\\\`` instead of `\section*{Introduction}`?

Comment: really so easy? Thanks so much!!

Comment: Actually, what you propose is better. Thank you!

Comment: `\Large` does not have an argument...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Whenever you see `\\\\`, you know that something is wrong with the document. ***Always***.

Also, you seem to be worried about blank lines: don't. They're good!

The problem you have is indeed the absence of a blank line before `\begin{footnotesize}`, so the final paragraph is broken into lines for typesetting when `\footnotesize` is already in force.

Here's an edited version of your document (using `\hoffset` and `\voffset` is to be avoided).

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper]{article} 
\usepackage{amsmath,amssymb}
\usepackage[
  textwidth=15cm,
  textheight=25cm,
  heightrounded,
]{geometry}

\usepackage[nopar]{lipsum} % for mock text

\newcommand\keywords[1]{\begin{center}\textbf{Keywords}\\#1\end{center}}

\pagestyle{empty} 

\begin{document}

\title{Title}
\author{%
  \textit{Author}\\
  University
}
\date{\today} 
\maketitle

\thispagestyle{empty}

\keywords{keywords}

\section*{Introduction}

\lipsum[1]
\begin{equation}
    u^{k+1}
\end{equation}
\lipsum[2]

\begin{footnotesize}\renewcommand{\Large}{\normalsize}
\begin{thebibliography}{9}

\bibitem{blabla} 
Blabla.

\end{thebibliography}
\end{footnotesize}

\end{document}
```

The `lipsum` package is just for filling with nonsense text. I also reduced the size of the heading for the references.

[image]

Comment: Your answer was very useful for me. Thank you so much!